# Unconfirmed balance in MultiBit HD plus unconfirmed transactions (failed bitpay orders)

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, multibit-hd

I've had a little bit of BTC in a MultibitHD 0.5.1 wallet for a while now. With the latest surge in price, I tried spend it at a place that uses bitpay. My first transaction probably had too little of a fee and is unconfirmed. I attempted to redo with a larger fee but it too told me was too small a fee and my attempt to buy from the store failed.

After some searching I found that Multibit is not good to use anymore / discontinued. I also came across something telling me to repair the wallet which I did but then the remaining balance became unconfirmed and not sure what to do next.

How could I get back the unconfirmed balance or confirm it? Is there anything I can do about my two unconfirmed transactions? Would it make sense to transfer everything to a new wallet software (can't when unconfirmed balance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [suggestion in the GitHub issues page](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/multibit-hd/issues/862#issuecomment-303613294) solved the unconfirmed balance in MultiBit HD.

I performed the following in Windows 10:

1. Closed the MultiBit HD Application
2. Navigated to the wallet data in `%AppData%\MultiBitHD\`
3. Rename the folder `mbhd-12345678-...` to `old-mbhd-12345678-...`
4. Reopen the MultiBit HD Application.
5. Restored from wallet words (Requires **words** and **datestamp**).

   *Note: I did not have to close the application during synchronization like the GitHub comment suggested.*
6. After synchronization, the unconfirmed balance was then confirmed. I was then able to transfer my balance to another address and software.

---

At the time it just appears to have been an over flooding of transactions making confirmation slow especially with my low fees (0.1 mbtc, 0.5 mbtc, 0.75 mbtc). Wallet balance transfer and the two unconfirmed transactions have been processed and confirmed.